# V8 : Isolate is incompatible with the embedded blob

Tags: v8, embedded-v8

I am trying to create custom snapshot from some Javascript file. I was able to create a snapshot using the command
`mksnapshot.exe snapshot11.js --startup_blob snap.bin` 
but when I was trying to create an Isolate with this snap.bin file I got this message
**`The Isolate is incompatible with the embedded blob. This is usually caused by incorrect usage of mksnapshot. When generating custom snapshots, embedders must ensure they pass the same flags as during the V8 build process (e.g.: --turbo-instruction-scheduling).`**

I am guessing that I need recreate the snapshot with the proper flags but I couldn't find which flags I need to use.
My **args.gn**

```
is_component_build=true 
v8_static_library=false 
is_official_build=false 
is_debug=true 
use_custom_libcxx=false
use_custom_libcxx_for_host=false
target_cpu="x64"
use_goma=false 
v8_use_external_startup_data=false 
v8_enable_i18n_support = false 
symbol_level=2 
v8_enable_fast_mksnapshot=true
```

Any lead will be helpful.
10x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can invoke `ninja` with `-v` to have it print all the commands it executes; e.g. if you compile V8 with:

```
ninja -v -C out/... v8_monolith
```

then you'll find a line for the `mksnapshot` invocation in the output, and can copy the flags from there. (If you have already compiled V8, ninja will say "nothing to do"; in that case you can either clean out everything, or just delete `snapshot_blob.bin` and `libv8_monolith.so`.)